# PCA, highly explained component with no value above 0.3

Tags: pca, eigenvalues, factor-rotation

I was analyzing PCA output, and when I reached "*pca $xlist, comp($ncomp) blanks(.3)*" to name variables, I found out that **component 1. which explains more than 50% didn't have any variable above 3**, yet most of the macroeconomic variables under it were above 1.

How should I deal with it? The other 5 components had variables above 0.3, but I don't know what to name component 1.

Comment: Could you please explain what the numbers in "variable above 3" and "variables above 0.3" mean?  Note that the components of a PCA are defined only up to an indeterminate nonzero multiple: various conventions are used to fix that multiple, leading to different meanings of the PCA components.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what all your variables are, we can't possibly name a component.

When one PC explains a large proportion of the variance and all its loadings are roughly equal, then that is some sort of general PC. What are all your variables measuring?

For instance, with physical measurements, such a PC is often an overall size variable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I am researching the impact of macroeconomic variables on company’s performance. I have decided to use PCA to select macro vraibles.

Currently, I have 76 macro variables, and those are high correlatedly with each other, some even at 99% , and 98%

The results I got where confusing, first component which explains more than 50%, had no variables correlated with at 0.3 or even 0.2, but instead I got so many components less than 0.2 and above 0.1.  

So what do you suggest I do with component 1?

Comment: I would not use PCA to select variables. That's not its purpose. You might try LASSO.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try.